# cookie is not getting set in Mozilla firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set the cookie before accessing the url. The code is working fine in Google chrome browser, but in IE or Mozilla Firefox, Cookie is not getting set.
Here is the piece of code for reference:

```
  jQuery.setCookie("ABC", jsonRes.enCookie,1,".ABC.com");
  window.location.replace(jsonRes.redirectURL);
```

Comment: Where does `jQuery.setCookie` come from? Looks like a plugin...

Comment: are there any errors being reported in the browser console? Also, what browser versions are you using?

Comment: can you point out what plugin you are using?

Comment: I am using JQuery plugin in my code. There is no any errors in browsers. I have checked the Cookie time to time and I found that the cookie is not being set using this piece of code while It works in Chrome.